# windows-7: could not run android apps on device

Tags: android

I'm trying to import android applications from other computers. after sometime they're running on emulator finally now but not on the device .
probably the reason is the driver I installed , because adb devices did not recognize the device so I installed this manually and still Bluetooth Peripheral Device not installed when I check in device manager!

at first it gave me this error : `the app stopped running unexpectedly !`

now the error is :

```
Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
Please execute 'adb uninstall com.newboston.aida.android2' in a shell.
Launch canceled!
```

any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I don't see a reason for this to be a Windows-7 problem, hence removed Windows-7 tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just typed adb uninstall and then the name of the package in command prompt and it works !

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the application from android device or emulator, and try to re-run / install the application. Because **debug.keystrore** is different for every devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new virtual device. Maybe it'll work when you install the driver first. It's possible, that your phone will be recognized then. And I don't think win7 is the problem.

Comment: I did that and again the same error ! actually I'm a Mac user and I don't have this issue with android in Mac!

Comment: But that doesn't mean, that windows is the problem. I think there's an error with your android installation. You should reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

If possible can you just Change the Package name of the current working project. And try to Build it. it might get other path and would run. This is a kind of Patch i know, but just try it out....

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem while moving the application from one system to another... some time the problem comes due libraries path and the api level.

So you can check the api level is the same in the application buildpath in the other system.

Hope this will help you.